# How can I predetermine the ideal size I should make a hash table for N items?

Tags: python, hashtable, probability

If I calculate the probability of collisions using:

```
def collision(hash_t, items):
    prob = 1.0
    for i in range(1, items):
        prob *= (hash_t - i) / float(hash_t)
    return 1 - prob
```

Is there an easy way to create a model that will calculate the cost of lookups and insertions in the hash table based on the probability of collisions, so then I could decide the optimum size based on the speed v memory allocation?

Comment: `probability of collisions` can be determined only when we use the actual hashing algorithm?

Comment: Just to make sure I follow this question, you already know (implicitly based upon this function) the distribution of your data set?

Comment: @thefourtheye yes, I had imagined I could manually input the  number of items with the same hash value in a specified hash table size based on the probability values and then time the lookups etc.. but for large amount of collisions in a large hash table that would take forever.

Comment: Have you attempted using statistical methods to sample your dataset to estimate the probability of collision?  Keep in mind that a 20% chance of collision each of which result in a 2-chain lookup is much less expensive than a 20% chance of collision where every item is placed in the same bucket (maybe a 400-length chain lookup).

Comment: @BlackVegetable, I am doing an online course and somebody asked what would be the optimum size a hash table should be for say 10000 entries, I googled and came to the conclusion that it comes down to speed v memory trade off, I just started learning about hash tables  today so could you expand on your suggestion?

Comment: The distribution of your data matters as well as your hash function.  If upon applying your hash function to your dataset, all of your data maps to the same value, the size of your hash table won't matter -- other buckets will remain unused.  If your data set can be assumed to be normal or uniform then you can start analyzing an optimal hash table.  Read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Key_statistics for more details on what I was mentioning.

Comment: It may be helpful to continue this conversation via chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50146/private-convo-hash-tables .  We can post the results of our conversation as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this depends on your hashing function + data type (to determine how the hashing takes place), the size of your hash entries (which with python can vary from 32-bit systems vs. 64-bit systems), your collision handling strategy, and your time/memory requirements, the following is a good rule of thumb:

Use a load factor of 2/3.

That is, have a hash table that is 3/2 the size of your number of elements.  So if you have 1,000 elements, you have 1,500 entries.  If each hash element is 32 bits (assumption based on a 32-bit python installation, if this is wrong someone correct me) then you are *wasting* almost 2 kB, which is truly a tiny amount of memory.  If you had 2,000,000 entries, you would waste almost 4 MB which also is tiny.

In short, the common consideration in hash tables is rarely space, but rather time.  Python's own implementation used with dicts uses a 2/3 load factor maximum before expanding the hash table size.  This is based upon a performance degradation with many collision strategies performing poorly around 70% or 80% load factor.